# Websphere MQ .NET API versions conflict

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, ibm-mq, mq

All,

I manage to connect with MQ Websphere version 6 from C# using two DLLs from IBM:

```
amqmdnet.dll (assembly version: 1.0.0.3)
amqmdxcs.dll (assembly version: 6.0.0.0)
```

The above assemblies are deployed locally with my application.

However if try in a server that already has MQ Websphere version 7 installed in the GAC then I have a big issue.

Basically the above two DLLs are in the GAC but they are very different from the ones I have as they are for version 7. However the assembly version is the same. 
Hence my application fails because it picks the version 7 assemblies as they have the same assembly version and same public key token.

One solution is obviously removing the version 7 DLLs from the GAC. 
Is there any other option?

Thanks
MK

Comment: It is true that the version numbers of the dlls are same with MQ v6 and V7. Can you provide details of the big issue that you are facing?

Comment: not enough detail to answer this question effectively.